# How to concatenate variables?

Tags: javascript

I have some variables home1, home2 and home3 which contain values.
Now I want a loop with a counter variable to show the value of the home variables.
But how can I concatenate the variable so that I can loop them?

```
var counter = 1;
while (counter < 4){
  alert(home + counter);
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest to do is to assign them into an array instead and loop the array.

```
var homes = new Array(home1, home2, home3);
var counter = 0;
while (counter < homes.length){
  alert(homes[counter]);
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Didn't check my syntax, but this is the basic thought.

Comment: I agree it is better to use an array, but I have a history to deal with where the values are in separate variables. So I like this approach best. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would refactor this to use an array:

```
var homes = [ 'London', 'New York', 'Sydney'];
for(var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++)
{
    alert(homes[i]);
}
```

Concatanating variables to reference other variables as you are trying to do is not a good design, and shouldn't be done.

Note, it might be easier to use a `for` loop as I have done, it is arguably easier to read.  `homes.length` will return the number of elements in the array, so we will be loop through all of them in this instance!

Hope that's helpful for you.

Comment: Careful with your terminology - you might confuse someone! In your example, the variable `i` is both defined before and available outside the `for` loop.  Also, using a number can offer better performance than accessing a property, if the array length is constant.

Comment: @Andy thanks, I knew it was a bit of a messy phrase as I wrote it, i'll clean it up.

Comment: @Andy, I disagree with using a number though, isn't specifying < 4 a magic number?  It's going to probably cause OP more problems down the line, I'd stick with using the length if we are wanting to loop all elements in the array.

Comment: yeah, normally I'd agree with that and generally that's what I'd do. If order isn't a requirement, however, you'd be better off with a `while` loop and decreasing a number until it gets to 0, e.g. `counter = arr.length; while (counter--) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using an array for this. http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Answer (score 2):

You can only do that using `eval()` (unless all three variables are globals), but you shouldn't because it's not the correct approach.  Instead, you should use an array for your variables:

```
var home = [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ],
    counter = 0;

while (counter < 3) { // or counter < homes.length
    alert(home[counter]);
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 1;
while (counter < 4){
  alert(window["home" + counter]);
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```