# Creating a variable based on a loop.

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What I want to do is create a variable in Google apps script based on the i in a for loop. Also how can i code a loop to all the variable back. I want to do what i wrote in the code below, but it does not work.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i ++){
     var pieChart + i = Charts.newPieChart()
        .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,3]))
        .build(); 
  }
```

I then want to call use it kinda like this

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i ++){
        pieChart + i . do stuff with the it 

        }
```

Comment: You may think you want to create variables in a loop, but you really don't. What you want is a single object, and to create properties on that object. *(or an Array if you're always using numeric indices)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043439/how-to-concatenate-variables)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an **array**.

```
var pieChart = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  pieChart[i] = whatever;
```

Arrays in JavaScript start with element zero, not 1. (You're free to ignore element zero if you like, but it makes things awkward because the length of the array is figured as the largest populated index + 1.)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off to use an `array`, which would look something like this:

```
int[] pieChart;
pieChart = new int[5] 
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i ++){
     pieChart[i]= Charts.newPieChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,3]))
    .build(); 
 }
```